# Devise, modals, SSL and sign in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, devise

The typical "works on local development but doesn't in Production"...

This link works in Development, but not in Production due to... who knows what?

`<p><%= link_to "Login / Sign Up", new_user_session_path(:secure => true), class: "link", remote: true %></p>`

```
Started GET "/login" for 38.116.199.130 at 2012-11-27 13:02:03 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as JS
Processing by CoursesController#index as HTML
```

Yet nothing shows up in production.

Prior to using `:secure => true` in the link, the link was redirected due to SSL restraints caused by the following `Devise::SessionsController.ssl_required :new, :create`.

Is there some security protocol in JS that says "i won't show a link in a modal if the originating link is not in the same http protocol too?" I'm just guessing, but it's a tick off. Screaming "WORK!" isn't doing anything either, surprisingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW i had ssl_requirement as the gem handling my SSL in a rails 3.2 app. I forgot about force_ssl.  Adding [what is mentioned on the devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-SSL-%28HTTPS%29) helped sort it out.  Now the view still takes 7s to display though... but at least it works.